# mv command on remote server not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh, mv, here-document

```
B=$1
CHECK="$(ssh $USER@$LOGINHOST <<EOD
        . /path/loadprofile.sh
        if [[ ! -e \$TXTDR/$B.txt ]]; then; echo "TXT file for this job does not exist."; exit; fi
        mv \$TXTDR/$B.txt /tmp/$B
EOD)"
```

It is failing with exit code 1 and does not display any error message but the file that i am trying to move just vanishes. So i have two questions here.

1. Why is it failing? When I am trying same from command line, it
   works.
2. If it fails, why does the file that i am trying to move
   vanish? Is that how mv generally works?

NOTE: The script is running in bash shell and the default remote server shell is ksh.

Comment: What happens if you replace `mv` with `echo mv`? There is also `-v` option to `mv`.

Comment: Which variables are defined before this snippet of script is run? You reference `$USER`, `$LOGINHOST`, `$TXTDR`, and `$1`. The standard variable `$USER` is unnecessary - ssh will default to the current user account. You escape `$TXTDR` for evaluation on the remote host so I assume you set it in `loadprofile.sh` (but you don't say so). There's no check for `$1` or `$B` being empty, nor is there a check for it containing whitespace.

Comment: @roaima I have updated my post. Yes, i am loading the profile after connecting to remote server. Apologies, I posted a snippet of the script, not the complete script. There is a check for $1 and $B being empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The here-document delimiter, `EOD`, that is ending the document, must be on a line by itself.  The `EOD)` string is not equal to `EOD`.

`mv` does not remove files on failures.  Assuming `$B` does not contain whitespace characters and if the `TXTDR` variable is undefined by the remote shell, the command executed would be

```
mv /$B.txt /tmp/$B
```

(with `$B` expanded by the local shell before `ssh` is called), but that will definitely not delete `/$B.txt` if the target is not writable.

If `$B` contains whitespace characters, it needs to be double quoted (just like `$TXTDR` should be):

```
mv "\$TXTDR/$B.txt" "/tmp/$B"
```

---

For doing the particular thing that you are using this code snippet for, I would probably have written it as

```
ssh "$user@$server" sh -s -- "$somepath/file.txt" <<'END_SCRIPT'
[ -e "$1" ] && mv "$1" "/new/location/${1##*/}"'
END_SCRIPT
```

or even just

```
ssh "$user@$server" sh -s -- "$somepath/file.txt" "/new/location/file.txt" <<'END_SCRIPT'
mv "$1" "$2"
END_SCRIPT
```

(which arguably does not need a here-document at all and could be shortened to `ssh "$user@$server" mv "..." "..."`)

... without outputting unnecessary text.  If you want to test for success, look at `$?` after this (would be zero if everything went ok).

This would also work:

```
if ! ssh "$user@$server" mv "..." "..."; then
    echo 'Something went wrong with ssh or remote mv' >&2
fi
```

Comment: Oh yes! That did the trick. I remember it used to work for me previously even with ')'. Can you please answer the second part of the question. Why does the file vanish if mv fails?

Comment: @Koshur I had to run for a bus. I will get back to this later. Others may supply fuller answers...

Comment: @Koshur Where is `$TXTDR` defined?

Comment: @roaima Ah, I am assuming its a code fragment rather than a complete script.

Comment: @Kusalananda me too, which is why I want to know what's defined where

Comment: @roaima $TXTDR is defined on the remote server. I forgot to mention that i load the profile after connecting to remote server. I still fail to understand what happens to the file.

Comment: @Kusalananda After updating EOD as above, now the file is getting moved but the exit code $? is still 1. I am not sure what's happening..

Comment: @Koshur Are you running your code but with a newline between `EOD` and `)`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, that's correct. EOD is on a line by itself followed by )" in the next line.

Comment: @Koshur I'm assuming it's because the test fails? The file does not exist?

Comment: The file is present and gets moved successfully but the return code is still 1.

Comment: @Koshur Sorry, I have no good explanation of that. You may want to do some debugging by echoing `$?` on the remote side (`\$?`) after the `mv` to see if it's the `mv` or something else that is causing the non-zero exit.

Comment: @Kusalananda My bad - I was not escaping $?. All set now.